# Probability of min(x,y)<1

Tags: probability

How can I solve this?

$f_{xy}(x,y)$ is a joint probability distribution defined by

$$f_{xy}(x,y)=ye^{-y(1+x)}$$  for $ x,y>0$.
And for other $x,y$ the joint probability distribution defiend by 
$$f_{xy}(x,y)=0$$

And the Question is Find the probability of:
P(min(x,y)<1)=?
Please Write Your Full Answer.

Comment: Draw the region $\{\min(x,y) < 1\}$ on the $x$-$y$ plane and integrate the density over that region.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can You Help me ?A simple Probability Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3060936/can-you-help-me-a-simple-probability-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$P(\min(x,y)<1)=1-P(\min(x,y)\geq 1) = 1-P(x\geq 1,y\geq 1)$$
$$ = 1-\int_{1}^{\infty} \int_{1}^{\infty} ye^{-y(x+1)}dxdy.$$
So we have that 
$$P(\min(x,y)<1) = 1-\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-(y+1)}dy=1-\frac{1}{e^2}.$$